# Does Azure DevOps support multiple templates per project?

Tags: azure-devops

Management would like to migrate all teams using Azure DevOps (VSTS) to a single project to make reporting and work roll-ups easier.  if this is done can the individual teams still utilize templates customized to their specific needs or would they need to use the default template for the project.

Thanks

We are being asked to migrate to a "standard" company project but don't know if we will be able to have customization for our process

Answer (score 2):

No. One team project has one process template. You can customize that process template however you wish, of course.

Comment: So all teams in that project must use the same process template.  I thought I had read that you could have team specific process templates as long as they were based on the Project Template. (Parent -- Project Template, Child -- Team Template)  If that is not the case I see very little reason to migrate to a single project.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create an inherited process in order to make your customizations, and change every Team Project to that Process.

You have to take into account that the customizations you have made to your Team Project could be affected when you change to a inherited process.

Test carefully with some test Team Projects before.